# Pre select an option in a select box

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, select

i've got the following select box, I'd like to pre select news when the page is loaded,

```
<select type="text" name="cn_terms[category][]" id="cn_metabox_category" class="form-control cn-taxonomy select2-hidden-accessible" multiple="" data-select2-id="cn_metabox_category" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true">
  <option value="32" data-select2-id="19">Community</option>
  <option value="85" data-select2-id="20">News</option>
  <option value="33" data-select2-id="21">Old News</option>
  <option value="1" data-select2-id="22">Uncategorized</option>
</select>
```

I've tried

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
$("#groupsel_0 option[value=85]").prop("selected", true);});
```

and

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $("#cn_metabox_category").val("85");    
});
```

but neither seem to work.

Comment: I believe `.prop()` *gets* the attribute; it doesn't set it.

Comment: You do not need javascript or jquery for that. Just add the `selected` attribute to the option tag

Answer (score 1):

The second version works. Fire up the snippet.

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $("#cn_metabox_category").val("85");    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select type="text" name="cn_terms[category][]" id="cn_metabox_category" class="form-control cn-taxonomy select2-hidden-accessible" multiple="" data-select2-id="cn_metabox_category" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true">
  <option value="32" data-select2-id="19">Community</option>
  <option value="85" data-select2-id="20">News</option>
  <option value="33" data-select2-id="21">Old News</option>
  <option value="1" data-select2-id="22">Uncategorized</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks, turns out the reason it's not working is because the selector is built using https://select2.org/

Answer (score 0):

When the page loads you can try this (you can put it in `<body onload="//put code here">`):

```
$("option[value='85']").attr('selected','selected');
```

Comment: Thanks, turns out the reason it's not working is because the selector is built using select2.org